# Equation for Figuring out the Displacement for a Projectile at an Angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile, displacement

I'm wondering if anybody can *simply* tell me if there is a *simple* formula to solve for displacement when you've been given the launch angle and initial velocity? See; http://is.gd/LpT1EA

To some, it may seem if I'm asking somebody to give me a *simple* way to explain it (as if I already know the answer but couldn't explain it to somebody well, hence me asking...). - This is not the case. I've watched this video a few times and can't work out what a formula for it would be.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the way to arrive at simpler explanations of a problem is to make simplifying assumptions and break the problem down into smaller and simpler parts until they are all so simple that you can understand them.

You might make these simplifying assumptions

- the thing being launched sits on an infinite horizontal plane.
- there is a uniform downward force that does not vary in any direction
- there is a vacuum (no friction)

You might initially split up the problem by considering horizontal displacement separately from vertical displacement.

You might therefore work out the horizontal component of velocity using trigonometry. From that you could work out how horizontal velocity and displacement vary over time.

Once you understand that fully, you could consider vertical motion independently of any horizontal motion.

---

**Spoiler alert**

Given the above assumptions, horizontal displacement over time is something like

$$x' = x + v_xt$$

where $t$ is elapsed time, $x$ is initial displacement at $t = 0$ and $v_x$ is horizontal component of velocity.

The horizontal component of velocity is

$$v_x = v\cos(\alpha)$$

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I looked at a video or two on from the one I linked, and that went over the idea of splitting Vx and Vy ('scuse the lack of subscript. :-) - anybody tries to edit this comment, he shall feel my wrath).  I must have missed that idea before in previous videos. I know it has been mentioned before.  So, that didn't really answer my question. It's helpful! - Very much so. But I'd like an actual formula for working it out. Sorry, I was tired when I wrote my original question, I used equation, not formula. I'll go and correct that now. :-)

Comment: @Alex: [answer updated](http://maxcdn.fooyoh.com/files/attach/images/591/823/097/007/spoon.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula for that if I think this is what you mean:

$R$ or range is the horizontal displacement, $v_0$ is the  initial velocity,
$v_{0x}$ is the x-component of the  initial velocity, $\theta$ is the initial angle, $y$ is the horizontal displacement, and $t$ is the time when it is still on the air.

The formula is:

$$R=\frac{v_0^2 \cdot \sin 2\theta}{g}$$

From our one dimensional kinematics, we know that $R=v_{0x}t$. I would be just straight-forward.
We know that $y=v_{0y}-\frac{1}{2}gt^2=0$ since it is on the ground, $0=v_0t \sin \theta-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$ then $t=\frac{2v_{0y}}{g}$. 
$v_{0x}=v_0 \cos \theta$ so $R=v_{0x}t$ would be $R=(v_0 \cos \theta) \cdot \left( \frac{2v_0 \sin \theta}{g}\right)$. That would be $R=\frac{v_0^2 \cdot 2\sin \theta \cos \theta}{g}$. You may or may not be familiar with the trigonometric identity $2 \sin \theta \cos \theta=\sin 2\theta$. Using the identity, we have: $R=\frac{v_0^2 \cdot \sin 2\theta}{g}$. And we are  done! We know if there is a formula, we know the formula, and we know where it came from! Fantastic!